# Can I create / Does SharePoint Foundation support page layout

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

can I create page layouts for SharePoint Foundation 2013? I used google and now I'm not sure what Foundation supports or what are limitations?
I found this example:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a2638a36-60bc-482c-b00e-ac8bcd3dd265/how-to-create-new-page-layout-in-sharepoint-foundation-2013

but there is no answer. Also I found this:
"Page layouts are a SharePoint Server Web Content Management feature. Not available in SharePoint Foundation."

So, question is: Can I create page layout using Visual Studio for Sharepoint Foundation 2013? Will it work or what limitations I have?
Sorry about this noob question...

Comment: I'm just confused, because some articles says that I can create it and other says it's not possible...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822368.aspx
"Applies to:  SharePoint Server 2013"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Web Part Pages and customize them through SharePoint Designer, but the more advanced customizations of pages through design manager is unfortunately unavailable in SharePoint 2013 Foundation.

Answer (score 1):

Page layouts are part of the Publishing Feature and are not available in SharePoint Foundation.