# SharePoint 2013 Foundation - Edit default page layout

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, page-layout, quick-launch, web-part-zone

Can we edit the default page layout which comes with the team site of SharePoint Foundation version 2013?

SharePoint does not show the Page layouts folder neither in designer or in any other places.

Can we modify a existing page layout of a team site in foundation version?
i just want to add a webpart zone in the quick launch area (PlaceHolderLeftNavBar)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Page layouts are part of the Publishing Feature and are not available
>   in SharePoint Foundation.

more [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83869/can-i-create-does-sharepoint-foundation-support-page-layout)

Comment: i am building a custom left navigation. Some of the data will be coming from a external database. So what is the best method to do this? a user control? i think webpart is not a good solution since we cannot add a webpart zone in a page layout in a foundation version of sharepoint 2013.

Comment: it depends on your logic. you cannot add zones but you can add the webparts themselves. you may want to take a look at external lists. anyway, user control seems like a good approach

Answer (score 1):

I know its very late to answer, but SharePoint foundation does not provide the publishing feature and hence we cannot create our custom page layouts.

But still you can use a WebPart page and customize it from SharePoint designer to look somehow similar to your custom page layout.

Comment: Thanks P S to take a time for correcting, i was about to edit the answer.